# The intended purpose of MvvmCross CreateBindingSet

Tags: xamarin, mvvm, data-binding, mvvmcross

So I recently came across an interesting scenario from one of my teammates.

They are currently working in a `Xamarin` project and leveraging `MvvmCross`. They have decided that they would like to use `CreateBindingSet` exclusively over bindings directly in xaml.

To me this seems like an anti-pattern for Mvvm. It's tightly coupling the behind code to the view model and it adds extra complexity to a platform that is designed to be bound in xaml.

I'm trying to understand if using this function in behind code is a good idea or not but I can't make heads or tails of it from the documentation.

**Can someone tell me what the intended use case is for `CreateBindingSet`?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to providing text-format binding statement which can be easily included in xml layout files, MvvmCross also provides a C# based syntax to enable bindings to be easily constructed using code.

This binding syntax is referred to as **Fluent** bindings.

For example

`MvvmCross` creates the relationship between the View and the ViewModel by the following  code:

```
var set = this.CreateBindingSet<MyView, MyViewModel>();
```

Then you can set the data-binding by `For` and `To` methods:

```
set.Bind(LabelUserName).For(x => x.Text).To(vm => vm.UserName);
```

With the fluent syntax we can continue to specify the binding type, such as OneWay, and TwoWay, etc, like this:

```
set.Bind(LabelUserName).For(x => x.Text).To(vm => vm.UserName).TwoWay();
```

**Fluent binding is especially useful in the iOS and OSX platforms where the Xml layout formats are not easily human-editable(in iOS and MACOS platform there is no such a xml file so we need to set binding in code behind).**

For more details you could check https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/fundamentals/data-binding.

Comment: Thanks for highlighting that. Yes, I did read the documentation as I mentioned in the question. I see it's particularly useful in that case but is that the main use for it? Is it intended just for that purpose or can it be used as a wholesale replacement for xaml bindings?

Comment: Fluent binding is an optional solution in xamarin.forms and android . But in iOS , I think it is the best solution .

Comment: I'm planning on accepting yours. I just want to give some other people the opportunity to answer. As soon as there's a selected answer it'll drop out of a lot of peoples queue. Thanks again, I already passed this on to the team.